# Which skyscrapers in Tianjin, China have observation decks?

Tags: china, tianjin, observation-decks

Apart from the TV tower, are there any skyscrapers in Tianjin where the public can access an observation deck? I'm sure there are information online for whoever speaks Chinese, but that's not me...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find tall buildings with a publicly accessible view at an upper floor?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30782/how-can-i-find-tall-buildings-with-a-publicly-accessible-view-at-an-upper-floor)

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder The accepted answer to that question says that the final step after doing research could be to ask here. Seeing as OP has said they had trouble finding any English language guides, it is not reasonable to mark this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

This English language website about the [**Tianjin Global Financial Center**](https://www.som.com/projects/tianjin_global_financial_center) says

> an observation deck and sky restaurant at the top floors provide public access to a 360-degree view of the city.

[image]

---

Also the incomplete [**Goldin Finance 117 Tower**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldin_Finance_117) is expected to have a public observation deck, when finished in 2020.

Comment: Thanks for doing the research, but I'm afraid the information on that site just isn't true. I went to the tower and was met with confusion in the lobby - there is no observation deck open to the public.